# Running a class WITHOUT jUnit as a running option

Tags: java, junit

So I just ran a jUnit test with Eclipse. I have a test source folder and I have a general source folder for the normal classes that are not tests. Everytime I run my project, the tests (and Test.java) is the only thing that runs. The only time I am able to access the normal classes in my general source folder, is if I throw an @Test annotation in front of the main. 
Is there someway to go back to running from the normal source, without deleting the test source? Do I have to change the Run As configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a main method to run the regular java class. And if you do that, you should be able to right-click > Run As > Java Application

Comment: I have a main method in the General class, are you suggesting I make a new class file and run a main through that ?

Comment: You shouldn't need a new class then, just right-click and Run as...

Comment: When I try it this way, there aren't any run as options. It says "none-applicable"

Comment: It's hard to give any other recommendation because that is the only way I know how to run a particular class when my Run configurations are set on something else

Answer (score -2):

As **cricket_007** mentioned you need a `public static void main(String[] args){...}` method in one class to run it.

Comment: Seriously, making a one line answer out of the comment of another user?

Comment: It is the answer, nonetheless. cricket_007 is welcome to post it as an answer if he wants to.